# Installation error code: -26 while upgrading application

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow, app-update

When I'm trying to upgrade my application on an Android M device, I'm getting an error as:
"**App not installed.**" on the device.

The logcat says:

```
03-17 14:12:32.161: W/InstallAppProgress(18572): Replacing package:com.test.upgrade
03-17 14:12:32.164: D/AudioFlinger(386): mixer(0xb4310008) throttle end: throttle time(4)
03-17 14:12:32.243: I/LaunchCheckinHandler(1783): Displayed com.google.android.packageinstaller/com.android.packageinstaller.InstallAppProgress,wp,ca,106
03-17 14:12:32.243: I/ActivityManager(1783): Displayed com.google.android.packageinstaller/com.android.packageinstaller.InstallAppProgress: +107ms
03-17 14:12:32.244: I/Keyboard.Facilitator(2895): onFinishInput()
03-17 14:12:32.263: D/Finsky(19175): [1] PackageVerificationReceiver.onReceive: Verification requested, id = 5
03-17 14:12:32.284: D/Finsky(19175): [1] WorkerTask.onPreExecute: Verification Requested for id = 5, data=file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/testupgrade-release(4).apk flags=18 fromVerificationActivity=false
03-17 14:12:32.294: D/OpenGLRenderer(18572): endAllActiveAnimators on 0xb8ce3950 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xb8adfba0
03-17 14:12:32.629: W/SurfaceFlinger(361): couldn't log to binary event log: overflow.
03-17 14:12:34.211: D/Finsky(19175): [1] PackageVerificationService$1.onResponse: Verification id=5 response=0
03-17 14:12:34.220: D/Finsky(19175): [1] PackageVerificationReceiver.onReceive: Verification requested, id = 5
03-17 14:12:34.253: D/DefContainer(19477): Copying /storage/emulated/0/Download/testupgrade-release(4).apk to base.apk
03-17 14:12:35.210: W/PackageManager(1783): Package com.test.upgrade new target SDK 22 doesn't support runtime permissions but the old target SDK 23 does.
03-17 14:12:35.462: D/InstallAppProgress(18572): Installation error code: -26
03-17 14:12:37.503: I/SFPerfTracer(361):      triggers: (rate: 23:1168) (compose: 0:3) (post: 0:1) (render: 12:263) (171:15181 frames) (172:17292)
03-17 14:12:37.503: D/SFPerfTracer(361):        layers: (4:12) (FocusedStackFrame (0xb8b20fc0): 1:416)* (DimLayer (0xb8b08448): 0:129)* (DimLayer (0xb8bc0988): 0:12)* (StatusBar (0xb8b62628): 0:3907) (com.android.systemui.ImageWallpaper (0xb8b33c88): 0:108)* (DimLayer (0xb8b39238): 0:741)* (DimLayer (0xb8b64828): 0:82)* ( (0xb8bb6128): 0:35) (NavigationBar (0xb8bcaca8): 0:299) (com.google.android.packageinstaller/com.android.packageinstaller.InstallAppProgress (0xb8bcfac0): 0:124)- (com.google.android.packageinstaller/com.android.packageinstaller.PackageInstallerActivity (0xb8bce7f8): 0:54)- (com.google.android.packageinstaller/com.android.packageinstaller.InstallAppProgress (0xb8bbbc28): 172:198)
```

What is the significance of install error code -26?
My earlier app  target SDK version was 23 and newer app target SDK version is 22.
The logs include:

```
Package com.test.upgrade new target SDK 22 doesn't support runtime permissions but the old target SDK 23 does.
```

While no new permission have been added in the newer upgrade application.

How can ensure that app is correctly upgraded on M devices with my target SDK version reduced to 22 from 23?

Thanking in advance for any kind of inputs.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem. After several times of installation, I find that target reduced is the reason. I first installed 1.4.2 version of my app with target 23, and then reinstall 1.4.3 version with target 22, it failed with information "Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_PERMISSION_MODEL_DOWNGRADE]". I repackaged the 1.4.3 version with target 23, and resintalled successfully. So I think the answer is that you should increase your target to 23 again.